# Enable logging in wix installer

Tags: wix

How can I enable logging in my wix project and set MsiLogFileLocation?
Now I am running my install.msi with command line arguments:

> msiexec /i install.msi /l*v InstallLog.log

I want to log my work always just running install.msi without any arguments. Are there any way to do that?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can tell WiX to use verbose logging like this:

```
<Property Id="MsiLogging" Value="v" />
```

but you can't specify where to write the file - msiexec has already determined that by the time WiX gets to set the property.  It'll default to `%TEMP%\MSI{random chars}.LOG`.  You could offer the user a checkbox to determine if they want to open that log, like this (assuming you're using the built in InstallDir UI template - it'd be possible with others as well, but this is a pretty simple example):

```
<Property Id="MsiLogging" Value="v" />

<UI>
  <UIRef Id="WixUI_InstallDir" />
  <Publish Dialog="ExitDialog"
  Control="Finish"
  Event="DoAction"
  Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
</UI>
<Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="View Installation Log" />

<WixVariable Id="WixUILicenseRtf" Value="license.rtf"/>

<Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="[MsiLogFileLocation]" />
<CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />
```

This would copy the log file to a directory about as late as possible in the game, but would miss at least some of the tail end of the log:

```
<Property Id="MsiLogging" Value="v!" />
<CustomAction Id="CopyLog" Execute="immediate" 
              ExeCommand="cmd /c copy [MsiLogFileLocation] C:\temp\log.txt" 
              Directory="TARGETDIR" 
              Impersonate="no" 
              Return="asyncNoWait" />

<InstallExecuteSequence>
     <Custom Action="CopyLog" OnExit="success" />
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

Note that this won't work for the `C:` drive root, because that requires administrative privileges.  If you're ok missing even more of the log, you could change `OnExit='success'` to `After='InstallFinalize'` and change the `Execute` attribute on the `CustomAction` to `commit`.  That should allow it run as administrator.

See this discussion for a bit more: http://windows-installer-xml-wix-toolset.687559.n2.nabble.com/Setting-MsiLogFileLocation-property-td7374335.html

Comment: how can I copy logs from %temp% to disk C: and change their names on Disk C. i have two logs (the second is *_action.log)

Comment: Well, in that `WixShellExecTarget`, you could set the value to `copy [MsiLogFileLocation] c:\installer.log` or something like that.  But that's almost certainly going to require administrative permissions (i.e. that your installer run as administrator).

Comment: When I set property: <Property Id="WixShellExecTarget" Value="copy [MsiLogFileLocation] c:\installer.log" /> I receive error: The 'WixShellExecTarget' Property contains '[MsiLogFileLocation]' in its value which is an illegal reference to another property.  If this value is a string literal, not a property reference, please ignore this warning.  To set a property with the value of another property, use a CustomAction with Property and Value attributes

Comment: Ahh yeah you'd need to use another custom action...  hang on, I'll update the question.

Comment: Well.. I've been able to get it to copy the log, but it copies it before the entire log is complete - after all, the log contains information about the custom action to copy.  Not sure that's really what you'd want.  I still think the best route is to just display the log and let the user save it somewhere else.

Comment: You are right I need to copy logs and not displaying them to the user. It's not a problem that they aren't complete

Comment: Updated answer.  Again, this will cut off some of the log in the copy.

Comment: What does "v!" mean?

Comment: v! forces the stream to flush more frequently when writing the log.

Comment: @DanField Can you please upload the working sample in GitHub? It will be very useful for everyone.